# AJAX & CanvasJS - Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input when attempting to live update a graph by receiving JSON from a web page

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, canvasjs

I'm trying to get a graph to live update through CanvasJS and I'm using AJAX to receive JSON data from a webpage (it displays JSON data on the webpage initially from a MySQL database).

The data on the web page is of this form: [{"ID":"20","dateandtime":"2017-11-13 18:06:49","temperature":"14"}]

For some reason I get a console log error stating:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload (index.php:36)
```

And here is my `index.php` code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload = function () {

var dps = []; // dataPoints array
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 title :{
  text: "Dynamic Data"
 },
 axisY: {
  includeZero: false
 },      
 data: [{
  type: "line",
  dataPoints: dps
 }]
});

var xVal = 0;
var yVal = 0; 
var updateInterval = 1000;
var dataLength = 20; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

var updateChart = function (count) {

 count = count || 1;

 for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
     var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); //attempting AJAX here
     ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://websitewhereIgetmyphpdatafromdatabase.php');
     ourRequest.onload = function() {
         //var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText)
         var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
         yVal = ourData[0].temperature;
      xVal = ourData[0].dateandtime;
      dps.push({
       x: xVal,
       y: yVal
      });
     }
     ourRequest.send();
 }

 if (dps.length > dataLength) {
  dps.shift();
 }

 chart.render();
};

updateChart(dataLength);
setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width:100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```